# The report parameter has a DefaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter . Forward dependencies are not valid

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

[image]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[R$20_covid_application] 
    @Guarantors int,
    @CustNo int, 
    @Months tinyint = null 
WITH EXECUTE AS SELF
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        L.CUSTNO
        ,CUST_NAME1
        ,CUST_NAME2
        ,CUST_NAME3
        ,CUST_NAME4
        ,L.BRANCH
        ,REFER_NO
        ,RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, L.CUSTNO), 6) + ' - ' + CAST(LOAN_PRODUCT AS CHAR(4))  + ' - ' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, LOAN_ACC_SEQ_NO), 2) ACC_STR
        ,[CHECK_PRIN]
        ,[L_PRIN]
        ,[L_INT]
        ,[L_INTLQ]
        ,[L_EXP]
        ,[L_ACCR]
        ,[INV_BILL_CHARG_AMT]
        ,[P_PRIN]
        ,[P_INT]
        ,[P_OTH]
        ,[P_EXP]
        ,[P_PRV_S_INT]
        ,[P_ACCRUED]
        ,[P_OFF_ACCR]
        ,[MATURITY_DATE]
        ,[AFM]
        ,[TEL_1]
        ,[TEL_2]
        ,[CUST_ADDRESS]
        ,[SIGN]
        , CITY = CASE L.BRANCH 
                    WHEN 101 THEN '212'
                    WHEN 102 THEN '12321'
                    WHEN 103 THEN '123123Α'
                    WHEN 104 THEN 'ΚΑΛ12312ΚΑ'
                    WHEN 105 THEN '313Σ'
                    WHEN 106 THEN '132'
                    WHEN 107 THEN '12312'
                    WHEN 108 THEN '23123123'
                    WHEN 109 THEN '23123'
                    WHEN 110 THEN '123213123'
                    ELSE 'Unknown city mate' 
                 END
    FROM 
        LB.LM.LOAN AS L 
    JOIN 
        LB.LM.CUSTOMER_MF AS C ON L.CUSTNO = C.CUSTNO
    LEFT JOIN
        [asdf6].[fsdfsdf].[MASTER_Guarantors] AS G ON L.CUSTNO = G.CUST
    WHERE 
        ToClose = 0 
        AND L.CUSTNO = @CustNo 
        AND G.[SIGN] = @Guarantors
END
```

So this is the SQL of my stored procedure that works fine so far. The problem is that I have a 3 parameter report that does work because of dependencies on itself. What I want the report to do is to have a multi value parameter(drop down) that will have all the guarantors for the specific loan customer number. In the picture I posted you can see the error and the output I want in my report. (eg customer 1 has 2, 3, 4 as guarantors).

Some names have been changed

Comment: No image posted. What we will need to see if what the order of parameters is, their names,  and what parameter dependencies exist.

Comment: i changed the order to see if it works but nothing so far!!!

the order is 
custno
months
Guarantors

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `R420_covid_application` to populate the available values of your `Guarantors` parameter then that's the problem. You can't reference the parameter value in the dataset query that produces the parameter values in the first place.

It's difficult to tell from your description and you don't explain your dependencies but it sounds like you would need..

1. A Customer parameter (e.g. `@CustomerID`) which would be populated from a dataset query something like `SELECT * FROM myCustomers`
2. A Guarantor parameter (e.g. `@Guarantor`) which would be populated from a dataset query someting like `SELECT * from myGuarantors JOIN blah blah.... WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID`

This way the customers dataset does not depend on anything and when the users chooses a value the value of @CustomerID is set. Then, the 2nd dataset will be populated and filtered based on the value of @CustomerID.

If this does not help, you will need to edit your question and describe what you expect the user to see in each parameter and the dependencies from one parameter to the next. Give some sample data and expected results.

Comment: each loan customer has some guarantor for his loan. So what i want is the user to fill the customer parameter.with the customer id and automatically.the guarantor parameter (a multi value one)to be populated with the guarantor of the specified.customer. the stored procedure im calling takes data from different databases and schemas so that i can populate my report with customer ids names.addresses number of amortized loans etc.

Comment: ... which is basically what my answer suggests. If you are SURE you don't have any issues with recursive parameters then open the rdl file and change the order of the parameters in there, changing them in the parameters panel in the designer does not change the order, you have to do it in the rdl file directly. Take a copy first htough just in case it gets messed up.

Comment: Im a little bit confused with your answer tbh. As i cant join my stored procedure and the table with guarantors i will have to make my SP to populate a temp table that will be joined with guarantors table.

Comment: Did you try reordering the parameters in the rdl file first?

Comment: ofcourse!! its the first thing i did. I tried to create a new dataset and recall the SP. i changed all aggregates to my report to dataset1 so there is no collision now. but the results arent as expected. I cant pick the guarantors and there a no distict values. (eg at a table the customer's loan appear 2 times

Comment: So you edited the actual rdl file directly in a text editor, not using the designer?

Comment: I copied the <queryparameter><.../> and paste it at different positions to see if it works. Within the queryparameters tags ofcourse